# How to populate one sheet in a Google Doc with all the values from the other sheets?

Tags: scripting, google-docs

Our company has set up a tracker for closed cases. We have two sections we're tracking: Collaborative Sessions and Quick Close.

We have a shared Google sheet where each team member has a tab where they enter the information and then there's a Team tab that has all of them combined. Rather than entering the information twice, I want to script it to populate the Team tab.

In columns A-E in Team we have: 
A: Blank
B: Session Date (Date)
C: Case # Reviewed (Number)
D: Case Closed Date (Date)
E: Closed as a result? (yes/no)

Columns G through L:
G: Case Number (number)
H: Case Submit Date (date)
I: Case Grab Date (date)
J: Date Closed (date)
K: Number of days to close (number)
L: Notes

The first one will be populated in row 12.

In the separate tabs for each person, the columns are the same.

This is what I've got so far:

```
function populateTeam() {
  var ssh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var val = ssh.getRange('Paula!A4:E999').getValues();
  var sh_base = ssh.getSheetByName('Team');  
  var base = sh_base.getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = base.length + 1;
  var key = val[0][1].getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < base.length; i++){
  if(base[i][0].getValues() == key) {
      row = ++i;
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

This is based on another script I wrote to pull data from one sheet and populate another.

Problem is that it throws an error on line 7: it says "TypeError: Cannot find function getValues in object . "

How can I fix this? I figure that once I can get this to work, the rest of it will be pretty straightforward - just changing the columns and the sheet names.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using a formula such as:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A11:L;Sheet2!A12:L;Sheet3!A12:L},"where Col2 <>'' or Col2 is not null")`

See this example sheet to see it working: https://goo.gl/HjKwSc You can add more sheet names and ranges into the { } array and separate them with ;

Comment: I thought that this would work, but it only pulls from the first sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the formula you are using?

Comment: `=QUERY({Paula!A1:F;Vincent!A1:F;Billy!A1:F;Wendy!A1:F;Shirtal!A1:F;Jack!A1:F;Simi!A1:F;Anthony!A1:F;Lisa!A1:F;Brian!A1:F;Joseph!A1:F;Ronald!A1:F;Lotoya!A1:F},"where Col1 <>'' or Col1 is not null")`

Comment: Some regions use \ instead of ; so it may be worth trying `=QUERY({Paula!A1:F\Vincent!A1:F\Billy!A1:F\Wendy!A1:F\Shirtal!A1:F\Jack!A1:F\Si‌​mi!A1:F\Anthony!A1:F\Lisa!A1:F\Brian!A1:F\Joseph!A1:F\Ronald!A1:F\Lotoya!A1:F},"w‌​here Col1 <>'' or Col1 is not null")`

Comment: Also, is column A on each sheet a number or text?  In the where clause, use 'is not null' for numbers and <> '' for text, so you could delete one of these options as appropriate

Comment: Actually, column A is mostly empty. I got a parse error when I used the updated formula :( Any more ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that your first formula is returning all the data from each sheet in a single stack.  If you scroll down to row 1001, do you see data from the 'Vincent' sheet?  If so, amend the formula so it is just "where Col1 <> '' " at the end.  This should filter out the blank rows.  If that doesn't work try "where Col1 is not null" instead

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({Paula!A4:F;Vincent!A4:F;Billy!A4:F;Wendy!A4:F;Shirtal!A4:F;Jack!A4:F;Simi!A4:F;Anthony!A4:F;Lisa!A4:F;Brian!A4:F;Joseph!A4:F;Ronald!A4:F;Lotoya!A4:F},"where Col2 is not null")
```

Thanks, Chris!